# Why doesn't water accumulate at the Equator under the influence of the centrifugal force of the Earth's rotation?

Tags: forces, water, earth

During the rotation of the Earth, a centrifugal force is formed, according to the actions of which ocean water should be collected at the Equator, forming a "hump" hundreds of meters high.
However, there is no water hump on the Equator.
The depth of the ocean does not depend on latitude, although there should be such a dependence.
at the same time, the centrifugal force is sufficient to deform the shape of the earth from a regular sphere to a geoid!

[image]

Comment: I would simply say because of gravity. The centrifugal force is just a small correction to gravity

Comment: The [equatorial bulge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_bulge) is about $21$ km (difference of radii). That's a hump of more than a few hundert meters.

Comment: there is a plot here https://www.mometrix.com/academy/earths-structure/

Comment: Keep in mind, that oceans changes together with Earth shape, so it's already part of bulge. Ocean displacement can only form in a sudden Earth angular velocity increase, otherwise if changes are slow (like it was in Earth protoplanet mass formation),- oceans as well as Earth shape changed very early in Earth evolution and then adapts slowly further to angular speed changes.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/630859/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8074/226902

Answer (score 3):

> During the rotation of the Earth, a centrifugal force is formed, according to the actions of which ocean water should be collected at the Equator, forming a "hump" hundreds of meters high.

That is correct. The sea level at the equator is about $21\mathrm{\ km}$ further from the center of the earth than the sea level at the North Pole.

> The depth of the ocean does not depend on latitude, although there should be such a dependence.

This doesn’t follow. The equatorial bulge of the land is also about $21\mathrm{\ km}$. So the depth of the ocean is approximately uniform.

The idea is that on geological scales rock is also somewhat like a fluid. You can only have a mountain a certain height before it “flows” down. So the same centrifugal force that makes water bulge also makes rock bulge.

Comment: I don't believe that rock is actually a fluid over long time scales. Mountains don't *flow* down. They erode, and the sand grains and dirt they become are washed downhill.

Comment: @PeterShor On geologic timescales, I don't believe there's really any difference. Call it what you like.